# Two side by side Textviews with progress bar above and imageView below

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create two side by side Textview's both with centered text and of equal width, also with a progress bar above (top of screen) and an ImageView which should take up the remaining space below the two Textview's.

Here is what I have so far, currently the Textview's seem to be hidden.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/box1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/box2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are setting height to 0 dp in inside linear layout and also give some height in main layout too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/box1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/box2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

from

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

which is below progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Try doing as given below

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dip">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:max="100" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="box1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="box2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
```